# How do I coordinate a cluster of celery beat daemons?

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, celery, celerybeat

I have a cluster of three machines. I want to run `celery beat` on those. I have a few related questions.

1. Celery has this notion of a persistent scheduler. As long as my schedule consists only of crontab entries and is statically defined by `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE`, do I need to persist it at all?
2. If I do, then do I have to ensure this storage is synchronized between all machines of the cluster?
3. Does `djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler` automatically take care of concurrent beat daemons? That is, if I just run three beat daemons with `DatabaseScheduler`, am I safe from duplicate tasks?
4. Is there something like `DatabaseScheduler` but based on MongoDB, without Django ORM? Like Celery’s own MongoDB broker and result backend.

Comment: You should try asking this question on the [celery-users](http://groups.google.com/group/celery-users/) discussion list .. may have more luck finding experienced users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently Celery doesn't support multiple concurrent celerybeat instances.

> You have to ensure only a single scheduler is running for a schedule
>   at a time, otherwise you would end up with duplicate tasks. Using a
>   centralized approach means the schedule does not have to be
>   synchronized, and the service can operate without using locks.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html